# Matching hierarchical keywords to a document

Tags: python, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical keyword tree, represented as a list of tuples where the first argument is the "path" and the second is the corresponding keyword:

```
keys = [('0','key1'),('0,1','key2'),('0,1,12','key3'),('0,2','key4'),('0,2,30','key5')]
```

List connecting 'paths' and corresponding documents (one doc can have more than one 'path':

```
docs = [('0,1,12','doc1'),('0,2,30','doc1'),('0,1','doc2')]
```

I want to match each document to keywords and produce an outcome like this:

```
docdict={doc1:[('key1','key2','key3'),('key1','key4','key5')],doc2:[('key1','key2')]}
```

My question is how to get all the (parent) keyword most effectively? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more readable answer which will probably scale better if you have lot of these.

```
docs = [('0,1,12','doc1'),('0,2,30','doc1'),('0,1','doc2')]
keys = [('0','key1'),('0,1','key2'),('0,1,12','key3'),('0,2','key4'),('0,2,30','key5')]

keydict = dict(keys)
resultDict = {}

for doc in docs:
    (path, docname) = doc
    pathList = path.split(',')
    keyPath = []
    for i in range(0, len(pathList)):
        aPath = ','.join(pathList[:i+1])
        keyPath.append(keydict[aPath])

    if docname not in resultDict :
        resultDict[docname] = []
    resultDict[docname].append(tuple(keyPath))

print resultDict
```

Answer (score 1):

This almost does what you want:

```
>>> docdict = {doc[-1]:[key[-1] for key in keys if doc[0].startswith(key[0])] for doc in docs}
>>> docdict
{'doc2': ['key1', 'key2'], 'doc1': ['key1', 'key4', 'key5']}
```

and this does exactly what you specified:

```
>>> docdict = {}
>>> for doc in docs:
    docdict.setdefault(doc[-1],[]).append(tuple(key[-1] for key in keys if doc[0].startswith(key[0])))  
>>> docdict
{'doc2': [('key1', 'key2')], 'doc1': [('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), ('key1', 'key4', 'key5')]}
```

both is `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is also another solution:

```
keys = [('0','key1'),('0,1','key2'),('0,1,12','key3'),('0,2','key4'),('0,2,30','key5')]
docs = [('0,1,12','doc1'),('0,2,30','doc1'),('0,1','doc2')]

def get_path(p):
    # tuples so that you can use them as dict keys
    return tuple(p.split(','))

# we need to find the keys based on the paths, so make the path the dict's key
keypaths = {get_path(p): key for p, key in keys}

docdict = {}
for p, doc in docs:
    path = get_path(p) # we need the path as a tuple or list, so that you can get the parents via slicing
    # get all parents of the path and the path itself.
    # we remove one part of the path at a time and keep the original path also
    all_paths = [path]+[path[:-i] for i in range(1,len(path))]
    # you need to keep each doc/path combination alone, so you need a list to store it
    if doc not in docdict:
        docdict[doc] = []
    # add the keys whose path is in one of the parents or the path itself
    docdict[doc].append([keypaths[path] for path in all_paths if path in keypaths])

print docdict # now, you see what you expect. :)
```

Frankly, with all these one-liners, the code becomes unreadable. So, if you agree, you should like this solution better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I created first a method to get the direct parent from a keyword, but that does not answer the requirement. From what I understood, getting all parent keywords from a path is much better:

```
>>> def get_parents(keys, path):
    """ Get all parent keywords """
    # Get parent path (remove after last ',')
    parent_paths = [path]
    while ',' in path:
        path = ','.join(path.split(',')[:-1])
        parent_paths.append(path)
    return [key for path, key in keys if path in parent_paths]

>>> get_parents(keys, '0,2')
['key1', 'key4']
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def create_doc_dict(keys, docs):
    """ Create the required dict """
    docdict = defaultdict(list)
    for path, doc in docs:
        docdict[doc].append(get_parents(keys, path))
    return docdict

>>> create_doc_dict(keys, docs)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'doc2': [['key1', 'key2']], 'doc1': [['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], ['key1', 'key4', 'key5']]})
```